# Firefox leaves old snaps on disk

Tags: firefox, snap

I am using Firefox installed through snap (Ubuntu 23.04, snapd/lunar-updates,lunar-security,now 2.59.1+23.04ubuntu1.1 amd64). I have removed all but latest versions due to lack of disk space.
Installed should be only the latest version as reported by snap:

```
sudo snap list --all | grep firefox
firefox                    117.0.1-2                   3131   latest/stable/…  mozilla**
```

But then I have noticed that there are still old versions of firefox on disk:

```
ls -lh /var/lib/snapd/snaps | grep firefox
-rw------- 1 root root 243M maj 12 12:07 firefox_2645.snap
-rw------- 1 root root 245M jun  8 17:28 firefox_2748.snap
-rw------- 1 root root 245M jun 19 16:34 firefox_2760.snap
-rw------- 1 root root 245M jul 10 15:43 firefox_2880.snap
-rw------- 1 root root 238M avg  3 21:53 firefox_2952.snap
-rw------- 1 root root 238M avg 15 18:47 firefox_2987.snap
-rw------- 1 root root 237M sep 13 12:34 firefox_3131.snap
```

and

```
ls -lh /var/lib/snapd/seed/snaps/ | grep firefox
-rw------- 1 root root 239M okt 20  2022 firefox_1969.snap
```

Could I simply remove old version files manually or are they are needed for some reason?

Generally I have noticed difference if I run snap list --all or list files in /var/lib/snapd/snaps, there are some versions more left on disk.

Comment: I have two in `snap list` called `firefox_2993` and `firefox_3068`,  and three on disk. The one of these three that doesn't show up in the snap list (`firefox_3131`), is actually the most recent, downloaded yesterday. I can't explain why the latest wouldn't be the "active" one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can safely remove all but the latest two versions of the firefox snap package from `/var/lib/snapd/snaps/` in order to free up disk space.

The latest two versions of the firefox snap package to keep are listed in your question as follows:

```
-rw------- 1 root root 238M avg 15 18:47 firefox_2987.snap
-rw------- 1 root root 237M sep 13 12:34 firefox_3131.snap
```

Or show the files to keep more simply with `cd /var/lib/snapd/snaps/ && ls | grep firefox`

```
firefox_2987.snap
firefox_3131.snap
```

Comment: I have removed all .snap files, that are not in "snap list --all" output. Seem to do the job. Still, looks like a bug.